# How to merge branch to a master branch with or without changes?

Tags: git, merge, version-control

I am rather confused by this. In the following scenarios, how would you best add your local feature branch back to the master branch before pushing it back to the repo? Note that I am not using git from a terminal, I'm using [sourcetree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/), so I'm not very familiar with the git jargon.

**Scenario A**: No one on team pushed changes to Master

```
Master                A
                       \
Feature branch          B - C - D
```

**Scenario B:** Someone pushed a change while I was working on my local branch

```
Master                A - E
                       \
Feature branch          B - C - D
```

Comment: You will find it useful to become familiar with git jargon. Watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ffBJ4sVUb4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scenario A is trivial, because a normal push from the feature branch to `master` should succeed with no problem at all.  In scenario B, if we try to simply push Git will tell us that our feature branch has fallen behind `master`.  The two main ways to remedy this problem are merging and rebasing.

For the merge option, we can merge the `master` branch into our feature, and then merge feature out to `master`.  Here is the Git command for merging `master` into the feature branch:

```
git checkout feature
git merge origin/master
```

And here is a diagram showing what the end result of the merge option would be:

```
master:  A ---------- E ---- N
          \             \   /
feature:   B -- C -- D -- M
```

Here `M` is the merge commit resulting from merging `master` into the feature branch.  We needed to do that to bring the feature branch up to date with the remote `master`.  Then, to bring our changes into `master`, we made a merge commit in `master` as well.

Functionally speaking, merging gets the job done, yet as you can see from the history, it isn't always the tidiest way to do business in Git.  An alternative to merging is rebasing:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase origin/master
```

Here is what rebasing would look like, and I emphasize what you can see happening in the diagrams:

```
master:  A -- E
          \
feature:    B -- C -- D
```

The first step in a rebase is to rewind the feature branch to the most recent ancestor commit between feature and `master`, and then to play the new commits from `master` on top of the feature branch:

```
master:  A -- E
          \
feature:   E        [B, C, D commits not yet reapplied]
```

Next we reapply your unique commits on top of the new base:

```
master:  A -- E
          \
feature:   E -- B' -- C' -- D'
```

We can just rewrite this as follows:

```
master:  A -- E
                \
feature:          B' -- C' -- D'
```

Notice now that the feature branch is completely *ahead* of `master`.  Now a push or pull request should complete without any conflicts.

Comment: I see, thanks. But in the first scenario (and the last step in Scenario B), how do I "put" the feature branch on top of master, before I push to the repo? So that I would just end up with the master branch I mean.

Comment: @Moody Pushing the rebased feature branch to `master` _is_ how you put that branch on top of `master`.  Even though the steps of rebasing may seem complex (they are), the end result leaves you in a strong position, because your feature branch then is ahead of `master`.  Basically you are transforming scenario B into scenario A.

Comment: Okay thank you. I just wanted to make sure because I didn't want to push changes to the repo and mess things up for the rest of the team. I thought using "push" would send my feature branch as is to the repo without automatically merging it with master.

Comment: Well yes, it will, but so would pushing in scenario A.  If this be a concern, then most likely your organization will block direct pushes to `master` and instead make everyone go through a pull request.